# Box Shadow - Shadow Offset and Blur Gradient

Tags: css, gradient, box-shadow

I'm trying to work out how to achieve the box-shadow effect in the image linked to below. Basically I want no shadow at the top of the box, graduating to a shadow at the bottom.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgdSG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 1px rgba(184,184,184,1);

box-shadow: (horizontal) (vertical) (blur radius) (spread radius) (color)